# TypeError issue when implementing if-then logic in python

Tags: python, typeerror, databricks

I am using an if-then logic which looks like following. I want to convert the date format when the date column does not have any null values.

```
mask = df['date'].isnull()
df['a'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df.loc[(-mask), 'date'] = df['a']
```

It works in both my windows machine and Linux environment in ec2. But when I tried running in Databricks notebook it shows TypeError.

[image]

[image]

I need help to understand the error, especially when it runs without any error in other places

Comment: *Two* screenshots, and yet the important part of the error message is still missing...

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Sorry that it does not comply with the guideline. I usually recreate my problem with sample data and then post it. But in this case, the problem at hand is tricky to the extent that I don't know how to recreate it. On the other hand, I guess my code is too generic to make anything out of it.